# ng-options in angularjs does not get rebind after change in collection

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using dataFactory for getting collection by making api call.

```
    productApp.factory("productDataFactory", function($http){
  return {
    getUnits: function() {
      return $http.get('/unit').then(function(resp) {
        return resp.data; // success callback returns this
      });
    },
    getCommodities: function() {
      return $http.get('/commodity').then((resp) => {
        return resp.data;
      })
    }
  };

});
```

I use commodities collection in ng-options to populate options of select element.

```
<select ng-model='selected_Commodity' ng-change="updateGST()" name="commodity" id="commodity" ng-options = " c as c.commodity_name for c in <%= JSON.stringify(commodities) %> track by c "class="form-control  selectpicker" data-size="4" data-live-search="true" data-index="5" >
                              <option value="" ng-hide='selected_Commodity'>Select Commodity</option>
                              </select>
```

I am updating collection on a event. I am getting updated values in log. But It does not get reflected in my view.

```
var getCommodities = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    productDataFactory.getCommodities().then((data) => {
      if (data.type === 'success') {
        debugger;
        console.log("Inside factory ");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(  data.commodities ));
        deferred.resolve(data.commodities);

      } else {
        // $scope.commodities = [{name : data.type + data.msg}]
        deferred.reject([{name : data.type + data.msg}]);
      }

    })
    return deferred.promise;
  }

$('#commodityModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $scope.commodities = []
    getCommodities().then((data) => {
      $scope.commodities = data
      console.log("Inside Hide ");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(  $scope.commodities ));
      $("#commodity").selectpicker('refresh')
      console.log("Refreshed");
    })

  })
```

Please help me how can I rebind my select elements with updated values.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line inside a timeout like this and add timeout as a dependency

```
$timeout(function(){
   $("#commodity").selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the ng-options

**FROM**

```
ng-options = " c as c.commodity_name for c in <%= JSON.stringify(commodities) %> track by c "
```

**TO**

```
ng-options = " c as c.commodity_name for c in commodities track by c "
```